# CFAttributedString changing font size has no effect

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-text

I'm trying to draw text using CoreText and CoreGraphics. The text draws and positions fine, however I can't seem to be able to change font size. Or font for that matter. I tried setting attributed text with CFAttributedString directly and I tried changing the CGContext font size setting. Here's my code

```swift
//... (create CGContext)

let textAttrs = [
    kCTFontSizeAttribute as String : 18 as NSNumber
] as CFDictionary

let attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          NSString(string: "Hello, world!"),
                                          textAttrs)

let textLine = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString!)

context.textPosition = CGPoint.zero

CTLineDraw(textLine, context.textPosition)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the definition of attributes. First I had to define font and then apply font as attribute for string.

```swift
let fontAttributes = [
    kCTFontFamilyNameAttribute : "Courier",
    kCTFontStyleNameAttribute : "Bold",
    kCTFontSizeAttribute : 18.0
] as NSDictionary

let descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes(fontAttributes)
let font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(descriptor, 0.0, nil)
let attributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : font] as CFDictionary

let attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          "Hello, world!" as NSString,
                                          attributes)
```